# Load time in dropdown php

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I want to load dates in the first dropdown. In the second dropdown I'm loading time slots. If today's date[06-04-2015] is selected, then the time slot should load two hours from now. If next day's[07-04-2015] or [08-04-2015] are selected, the time slot should start from 9.00am.

So far my work is

```
<select class="form-control"  name="ddate" >
<option value="<?php echo date('d-m-Y') ;?>"><?php echo date("d-m-Y", time()) ;?></option>
<option value="<?php date("d-m-Y", time()+86400) ;?>"><?php echo date("d-m-Y", time()+86400) ;?></option>
<option value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y", time()+172800) ;?>"><?php echo date("d-m-Y", time()+172800) ;?><option>
</select>
<?php
$timeAtHalfHour = time() - ( time() % (60*60));
$timeAtHalfHour += 120*90;  //IDK IF YOU WANT THIS?
$endTime = strtotime('11:00 pm');
$numIntervals = ($endTime - $timeAtHalfHour) / (60*60);
echo "<select name='timeInterval'>";
$strTime1 = date('h:iA', $timeAtHalfHour);
foreach(range(1,$numIntervals) as $cur)
{
   $thisTime = $timeAtHalfHour + 60*60*$cur;
   $strTime2 = date('h:iA', $thisTime);
   echo "<option value=$cur>$strTime1 - $strTime2 </option><br />";
   $strTime1 = $strTime2;
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this in Javascript. On your question you mentioned:

> If today's date[06-04-2015] is **selected**

PHP is executed on the server side, it can't handle the event of selecting an element on your list.

Javascript can do that because it's running the browser side and you can handle this event. You can use JQuery to du what you want, here is a code snippet that can help you start:

```
$("form-control[name=ddate]").change(function(){
    $(this).children(":selected"); // This get you all the selected items
});
```

EDIT: The final code with JQuery and PHP:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <select class="form-control"  name="ddate" >
    <option value="<?php echo date('d-m-Y') ;?>"><?php echo date("d-m-Y", time()) ;?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y", time()+86400) ;?>"><?php echo date("d-m-Y", time()+86400) ;?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y", time()+172800) ;?>"><?php echo date("d-m-Y", time()+172800) ;?><option>
    </select>
    <?php

    echo "<select name='timeInterval' id='timeInterval'>";
    $start    = new DateTime('9AM');
    $end      = new DateTime('11PM');
    $interval = new DateInterval('PT1H'); // Set the interval to One hour
    $period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    foreach ($period as $dt)
    {
        $dt2 = clone $dt;
        $dt2->add(new DateInterval('PT1H')); // Add One hour
        echo '<option value="'.$dt->format("G").'">'.$dt->format("h:iA").' - '.$dt2->format("h:iA").' </option><br />';
    }

    echo "</select>";
    ?>


    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            var d = new Date();
            var hour = d.getHours()+2;
            $('#timeInterval option[value="'+hour+'"]').prop('selected', true);
        });
        $(".form-control[name=ddate]").change(function(){
           selDate = $(this).children(":selected").val();
           var d = new Date();
           var month = d.getMonth()+1;
           var day = d.getDate();
           var hour = d.getHours()+2;

           var curDate = (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day + '-' +
            (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
            d.getFullYear();

           // If selected date is equal to the current Date
            if(selDate != curDate)
                $('#timeInterval option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true); // Select 9:00 AM
            else
                $('#timeInterval option[value="'+hour+'"]').prop('selected', true); // Select the next 2 Hours
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok.... How to set the start time? It must start from 9.00 am if the next day is selected

Comment: I changed the tags for your question to the right topic. In the meanwhile, i'll try to get you the full code.

Comment: Yeah got it.. Thanks for the code... One small change. If we select today's date, then time slot should start from 2 hours from now....

Comment: Just edited my code, it's working now. Don't forget to set the answer as correct ;)

Comment: Yeah... Thanks for the code.... It works... Can't we hide the previous time slot of today's date???

Comment: Yes you can do it on the Javascript side.

Comment: Can u show me that too.... And one more question, When I save in db, Just the hours are saving. Minutes are not saving??? I have used varchar field..

Comment: You have to post a new question, so everyone can answer.